# What is concept of terms, keywords and term sets?

Tags: enterprise-keywords, term-set

Keywords: Within a SharePoint 2013 site, descriptive metadata (words or phrases) can be directly assigned to any list item or document; these words and phrases are called keywords.

1. Are the keywords and enterprice keywords the same thing.
2. What are terms?

Although terms are stored within a series of term sets, enterprise keywords are stored
within a single term set within the managed metadata service.

1. What are term sets? Can you give me a example so I can visualize this concept?
2. When do you convert a keyword to a term?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Terms** are the basic unit or smallest item in Managed Metadata or Taxonomy. **TermSet** is just a collection of Terms.Like say if you want to create a taxonomy for countries and their cities. Country will become the TermSet (eg:England) and cities will be Terms inside respective termsets ie London will be term inside England.

**Enterprise Keywords** is a site column under **Enterprise keywords group**. It is a managed metadata column and is mapped to a pre defined Termset called **Keywords**. See this [blog](http://www.siolon.com/blog/demystifying-the-enterprise-keywords-column/) which explains Enterprise Keywords in detail.

Comment: I would like to know how they work and more about their purpose, the articles aI read are very confusing.. Please can you point to easier articles